# Calling objects in chrome storage api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am having trouble making a chrome extension that needs to keep track of the user's total searches. My code creates an object in the content script and then adds to the object and stores it in chrome storage, however every time the content script runs again, I am pretty sure my object is being reset to an empty object. One idea I had was creating the object inside a background script and putting it in the storage then adding to the object in my content scripts, but I ran into issues with the object not being defined in my content script and went back to what I had originally.

Here is the important my content script:

```
var dataObject = {
    "searches": [],
    "links": [],
    "time": []
};

var key = 'myKey';

    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        key: dataObject
    }, function() {
        console.log('Value is set to:');
        console.log(dataObject);
    });

    chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
        console.log("Value is:");
        console.log(result.key);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Content script runs each-time the page is refreshed and in your content script your are first saving a pre defined object in the chrome storage. It will reset on each page refresh even if it is changed on some events.

Solution:
You will need to check first if the object(`myKey`) is saved in storage than you should just add new values to it.

Please note: Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page. Read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).